# TNSNAMES.ORA is located in Windows 2012 Server

Tags: oracle

Can you please any one help me for the following 
TNSNAMES.ORA is located in Windows 2012 Server? Can you please give the correct path for the same.

Comment: Could be a lot of places depending on whether the install was standard or custom.  Windows search will find how many versions you have

Comment: My Windows Server 2012 64 bit and only one Oracle instillation in the server.

Comment: What have you done to find the file? Isn't there a find function in Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can place the `tnsnames.ora` (and even more important the `sqlnet.ora` file) at any place. The question must be: How does Oracle find the files?

Have a look at this answer: [Determining locatation of relevant tnsnames.ora file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280883/determining-locatation-of-relevant-tnsnames-ora-file/28283924#28283924)

Answer (score 1):

it's in your $ORACLE_HOME\network\admin

**for example:**
C:\app\myusername\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora

Answer (score 1):

In case you have more than one oracle home and you want the one that is being used,
try running 
    "tnsping aaaa"
from command line.
This will "fail" but will give you the path to sqlnet.ora file which is in the same folder as tnsnames.ora file in most cases.